# Unity: avatar creation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, avatar

I'm making my own avatar builder in Unity and I'm stuck on a few key bits I need to implement.

Right now I have taken the avatar that Unity provide with its Mechanim tutorial and I've gave the hat a tag and have instantiated an object at that location. This point is simply an empty game object attached as a child to the head of the model. However I'm having issues making the newly spawned object move and stay with the head as the animation plays. When the avatar moves, the hat just stays in one static position.

How can I make it so that the hat stays with the players head and moves and rotates as the animation is rotating?

My code is really simple as I've no prior experience trying do what I'm doing so even if someone could point me in the right direction on how to build an avatar creator in Unity, I'd appreciate it.

My code as it stands:

```
    public GameObject equipItem;
public GameObject hat;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    hat = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Hat");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnGUI()
{
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0, 100, 50), "Equip Item"))
    {
        SpawnWeapon();
    }
}

void SpawnWeapon()
{
    Instantiate(equipItem, hat.transform.position, hat.transform.rotation);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is making the new object a child to the object you want it to follow. This can be done in the transform of the new object

```
void SpawnWeapon()
{
    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(equipItem, hat.transform.position, hat.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    newObject.transform.parent = hat.transform;
}
```

this is the same a dragging the new object onto the other object in the inspectors hierarchy window and thus causing it to inherit all transformations made to the parent